# Can't use $_SESSION with php login script

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have been researching for 2 days now as to why my script isn't working. All I wanted to do is create a simple sign up, login, logout script. I have the signup working just fine. When I go to login, the $_SESSION doesn't want to work and I have no idea why. Here's a bit of my code:

```
$userArr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$stored_pwd = $userArr['password'];
$id = $userArr['id'];

if (md5($password) == $stored_pwd) {
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id();
    header("Location: ".$redirect);
} else {
    $errors[] = "The passwords don't match. Please try again.";
}
```

So I have no idea what's wrong. I called the session_start() on all pages along with ob_start() and ob_flush(). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the session doesn't work'? What errors do you get, what exactly doesn't work? 'Doesn't work' is not an error message!

Comment: Saving passwords using `md5()` is only marginally better than plain text.

Comment: When I save the user's id to this $_SESSION variable, and then call it on the secured page nothing is returned. Also if I use "if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) { ... }" it won't show anything inside that block. Because nothing is in that variable apparently. I don't know why not. That's why I am saying it doesn't work.

Comment: dont use md5 for passwords. there are several well-established key ciphers that can hash a password slowly and securely (bcrypt, scrypt to name two)

Comment: also, are you checking your error logs? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, and ensure you are actually calling `require_once();` on a common file containing script variables needed everywhere (which includes the `session_start();`)